# Display concatenation of object schema field in Sanity Studio instead of last item

Tags: typescript, sanity

I'm quite new to Sanity and I'd like to know how to do this.

I'm adding items using the following schema

```js
defineField({
    title: 'Ingredients',
    name: 'ingredients',
    type: 'array',
    of: [
        {
            type: 'object',
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'ingredient',
                    title: 'Indredient',
                    type: 'reference',
                    to: [{ type: 'ingredient' }],
                    validation: Rule => Rule.required().error('Ingredient is required.')
                },
                defineField({
                    title: 'Amount',
                    name: 'amount',
                    type: 'number',
                    validation: Rule => Rule.required().error('Amount is required.')
                }),
                defineField({
                    title: 'Unit',
                    name: 'unit',
                    type: 'string',
                    options: { list: [...] }
                })
            ],
        }
    ]
}),
```

This works fine, but when adding the entity in Sanity studio it only shows the last item in the object like this
[image]

How do I get this to display with a concatenation of the object values?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a list preview after the fields array. You can find more help in Sanity docs here: https://www.sanity.io/docs/previews-list-views